# display an image captured from the camera or selected from the gallery on another activity in imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-gallery

I have two image buttons ,one for the camera and one for the gallery. I want to capture a photo with camera or to select a photo from gallery and that image has to be displayed on another activity in image view. My code doesn't work.

manifest.xml

```
<manifest ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
</manifest>
```

first activity:

```
private static int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
private static int SELECT_FILE = 1;
String imagePath;
String filename;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton take_photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
    ImageButton get_photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.galleryButton);
    take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    });
    //to get the photo from gallery
    get_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_FILE);
        }
    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            //file path of captured image
            imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            //file path of captured image
            File f = new File(imagePath);
             filename = f.getName();
            cursor.close();
            Bitmap imageData = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            imageData = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowPhotoActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("path", imagePath );
            startActivity(i);

        }
        else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath();

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagePath = selectedImageUri.getPath();
            Bitmap imageData = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            imageData = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowPhotoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", imageData );
            startActivity(intent);
        } } }
```

}

SecondActivity:

```
       ImageView showPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       image_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
       showPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: I can capture a photo,I can select a photo,but the image is not displayed on the other activity in imageview

Comment: And what part of displaying is failing?  Are you not getting the data in the intent?  Are you getting it but the file doesn't exist?  Does it exist but the decode fails?  Etc.

Comment: the last one..did you look the code ?